# debugging app on xperia over Ubuntu

Tags: android, debugging, ubuntu, adb, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to debug an Application on a Xperia cellphone with Cyanogenmod installed, but it doesn't seem to recognize my cell phone. Also, adb seems to be gone, I followed http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html the official guide, but when executing:

```
$./adb devices
```

on the plataform-tools/ directory the system doesn't recognize the device.

also I tried

```
$sudo ./adb devices
```

any ideas?

Comment: Did allow USB debugging on the phone in Settings->Application Settings->Development?

Comment: yes I allowed it. also I note I tried executing adb as sudo but nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to everyone for the help.!! I solved

the problem was that I needed to restart the adb server I did it like this:

```
$sudo ./adb kill-server
$sudo ./adb start-server
```